# two continuous font tag of the same size is invalidated in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, font-size

I'm using `< font size="">< /font>` setting the text font in UIWebview. And here is the problem :

when using font of different sizes, everything is fine.

```
< div>< font size=\"2\">text< /font>< /div><br/>
< div>< font size=\"5\">text< /font>< /div>
```

but when using font of same size continuously, the size of the font is set to default font size.
The effect of

```
<br/>< div>< font size=\"2\">text< /font>< /div>
<br/>< div>< font size=\"2\">text< /font>< /div><br/>
```

is equal to

```
<br/>    < div>text< /div>
<br/>    < div>text< /div>
<br/>which is obviously bigger than
<br/>    < div>< font size=\"2\">text< /font>< /div>
<br/><br/>
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<font>` tags have been deprecated for a very long time.  Use CSS instead.

```
<div style="font-size: 8px">small text</div>
```

Or even better:

```
<style>
  .small { font-size: 8px; }
</style>

<div class="small">small text</div>
```